# I can't parameterize the Entity Framework connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I tried to do this I saw on a stackoverflow forum to parameterize the connection string in EF. Try putting the `DbContext` constructor connection string

```
public DbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
```

Then create this string to return the connection string.

```
private string GetStringConection()
{
    var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
         {
             DataSource = "localhost",
             UserID = "sa",
             Password = "1234",
             InitialCatalog = "dbtest"
         };

    return builder.ConnectionString;    
}
```

While running I get the following Entity Framework error, I tried to find a solution but I don't know the exact error.

This is the code I use to test the execution:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     using (tallerdemecanicaEntities db = new tallerdemecanicaEntities(GetStringConection()))
     {
         var list = db.vta_factura.ToList();
         dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
     }
}

private string GetStringConection()
{
     var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
     {
         DataSource = "localhost",
         UserID = "sa",
         Password = "1234",
         InitialCatalog = "dbtest"
     };

     return builder.ConnectionString;    
}
```

This is the error I get:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException: The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development. This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework documentation here:
> [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715'](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715%27)

I use Visual Studio with Winforms, C#, the database to which EF connects is in SQL Server

Comment: What did your "fixed" connection string look like in your config file so far? Can you show us?

Comment: Look for questions on how to supply a connection string to an EDMX-generated context during runtime. That's different.

Comment: @marc_s At the moment the connection string of my app.config looks like this

  `<connectionStrings>
<add name="tallerdemecanicaEntities22" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DB.Model1.csdl|res://*/DB.Model1.ssdl|res://*/DB.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=dbtest;user id=sa;password=1234;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> <connectionStrings>`

Comment: I already found a solution, this worked for me

`public partial class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Path to your text File");
    }
}`

Sure, I made the string Get String Connection() public and static

Comment: Your current connection string is an **Entity** connection string - not a "plain" SQL Server connection string. You need to use the `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` - not the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` to create such a connection string